# Added second value to return and i don't know what's missing in the function's paramater to pass?

Tags: python, function, math, finance

Need help with this assignment, python newbie here, 30 minutes till deadline and i couldn't figure out what's missing. my teacher said it won't work like this.
updated,

```py
        if 0 < amount <= 20:
            return 0.005, 0
        if 20 < amount <= 50:
            return 0.893, 0
        elif 50 <= amount <= 100:
            return 1.000, 0
        elif 100 <= amount <= 200:
            return 1.900, 0
        elif 200 <= amount <= 300:
            return 2.800, 0
        elif 300 <= amount <= 500:
            return 3.500, 0
        elif 500 <= amount <= 700:
            return 4.000, 0
        elif 700 <= amount <= 1000:
            return 4.750, 0
        else:
            return 5.500, 0
```

Comment: What happens when you run your program? Does it produce any outputs that are wrong? Are there any errors?

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple @quamrana

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: has_enough_balance(50, 10, "P2P") @quamrana that's what i pass to test it

Comment: Please update your question with all the information we need. We need the full error traceback. Also what are the meanings of the numbers you return?

Comment: just did @quamrana

Comment: And what are the meanings of the numbers you return?

Comment: first value is fee for sender, second is for receiver @quamrana

Comment: And which one do you want to add `amount` to?

Comment: depends on how and where the function should be used later, it's an abstaract function @quamrana

Comment: Your `has_enough_balance()` function wants to add `amount` to something. That doesn't sound abstract.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here

```
def has_enough_balance(balance, amount, transaction_type):
    return balance >= calculate_fee(amount, transaction_type) + amount
```

calculate_fee() returns a tuple , in your has_enough_balance() function, you add the amount to it, you cant add a numeric and a tuple

index `calculate_fee(amount, transaction_type)` to choose which variable you want to use there and your code should be fine

"depends on how and where the function should be used later, it's an abstract function "
you could edit your has_enough_balance() function to

```
def has_enough_balance(balance, amount, transaction_type, fee_type):
    index_dict = {"sender":0, "receiver":1}
    
    return balance >= (calculate_fee(amount, transaction_type)[index_dict[fee_type]]) + amount
```

basically since you have `calculate_fee()` returning a tuple, you only want to use one of those values at a time.

you can follow the tuple with `[*index of the value you want to use*]` to grab the correct value. so I added `fee_type` as a argument for `has_enough_balance()` and a dictionary inside to let you say whether you want to use your function for the sender fee or the receiver fee, and the dictionary will match it to its corresponding index, and `[index_dict[fee_type]]` grabs the correct slice out of `calculate_fee()`

Comment: you're a life saver! can you walk through the logic please?

Comment: edited with a walkthrough, this was made with readability in mind but you could just put 0 or 1 for fee_type and get rid of every mention of the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Your `calculate_fee` method returns two variables.
In python, when you return multiple variables that's a tuple (example: `(0, 0)`)

But in this block of code

```
# Checking if client has enough balance before request is sent
def has_enough_balance(balance, amount, transaction_type):
    return balance >= calculate_fee(amount, transaction_type) + amount
```

You try to compare it to a single variable `balance` and you also try to add it to a single variable `amount`. These operations are not supported between a tuple, and an int.

From your comment i saw that `calculate_fee` returns the fee for the sender and the fee for the receiver.
You could edit your `has_enough_balance` function with a boolean parameter `forSender` to know if you're calculating the amount for the sender or for the receiver.

You could then use the value of this parameter to know which of the two fees you need to add in your calculation.

```
# Checking if client has enough balance before request is sent
def has_enough_balance(balance, amount, transaction_type, forSender):
    senderFee, receiverFee = calculate_fee(amount, transaction_type)
    fee = senderfEE if forSender else receiverFee
    return balance >= fee + amount
```